# Slow response time for Bad requests (Service exceptions) spring boot with zuul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I have spring boot micro-services deployed with zuul gateway and Eureka which is working fine, but I notice that when a request sends out bad request, which actually throw an exception from service class (Invalid User/Customer Id) the relevant error response took more than 2 Seconds. The success scenarios are working fine with acceptable response times. As you can see in the below log the ERROR took more time. These services are hosted in AWS, but it worked fine in the local environment without zuul integration.

```java
2020-04-03 04:14:38.102 DEBUG 14156 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] c.t.book.filter.AuthorizationFilter  : Auth UserId in filter: uid-b7e9d6f7-f5bf-4e74-9ac1-1d1120ceb43f
2020-04-03 04:14:38.103 DEBUG 14156 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] c.t.t.controller.TransactionController   : Create transaction inputs: {"bookId":"bid-1","customerId":"cid-8","transactionType":"credit","amount":5000.0,"note":"date validation test","dueDate":1585026193934,"imageUrl":"http://123.com","customerBookType":null,"requiredAvailable":true}, timeZone: Asia/Colombo
2020-04-03 04:14:39.884 ERROR 14156 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] c.t.t.controller.TransactionController   : Invalid customer id for the transaction: {"bookId":"bid-1","","transactionType":"credit","amount":5000.0,"note":"date validation test","dueDate":1585026193934,"imageUrl":"http://123.com","customerBookType":null,"requiredAvailable":true}

com.book.exception.InvalidUserException: Invalid customer id
```

Also I tried sending request directly bypassing the zuul, but here also I am getting the delay.
Please look in to this, If you need more information on this, let me know.

**Updated**

I notice that this happens intermittently, like the first call and second call takes more than 2 seconds then following 4 to 5 requests take normal time, then again one request take more time. But in the local environment this behavior is not there. (As I mentioned earlier this happens only for ERROR scenarios)

**Code**

Service class

```java
public Customer updateCustomer(CustomerUpdateRequestDto customerUpdateRequestDto) {
        try {
            String customerId = customerUpdateRequestDto.getCustomerId().trim();
            Optional<Customer> customerOptional = customerRepository
                    .findById(customerId);
            if (customerOptional.isPresent()) {
                Customer customer = customerOptional.get();
                customer.setDisplayName(customerUpdateRequestDto.getName().trim());
                customer.setImageUrl(customerUpdateRequestDto.getImageUrl() == null ?
                        null : customerUpdateRequestDto.getImageUrl().trim());
                customer.setMobileNo(customerUpdateRequestDto.getMobileNo().getDisplayNumber());
                customer.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
                customerRepository.save(customer);
                return customer;
            } else {
                throw new InvalidUserException(INVALID_CUSTOMER_ID);
            }
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new BookException(FAILED_UPDATE_CUSTOMER, e);
        }

    }
```

Method call from the controller

```java
    private ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> updateCustomerIfValid(CustomerUpdateRequestDto customerUpdateRequestDto) {
        try {
            Customer customer = customerService.updateCustomer(customerUpdateRequestDto);
            CustomerResponseDto customerResponseDto = new CustomerResponseDto(customer);
            log.debug("Updating customer: {} was successful", customerResponseDto.toLogJson());
            ResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                    new ResponseWrapper(ResponseStatusType.SUCCESS, SUCCESS_MESSAGE_UPDATE, customerResponseDto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseWrapper, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (InvalidUserException e) {
            log.error("Updating customer was failed for customer: {}", customerUpdateRequestDto.toLogJson(), e);
            return getBadRequestError(ErrorResponseStatusType.INVALID_CUSTOMER_ID);
        }
    }

    protected ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> getBadRequestError(ErrorResponseStatusType errorResponseStatusType) {
        ResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                new ErrorResponseWrapper(errorResponseStatusType, null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseWrapper, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: if you by pass the zuul, then also taking time to response means, it should not problem will zuul gateway. can you add exceptionHandler and related code?

Comment: @techzone4all I have added the code from service and controller, here the InvalidUserException is the expected scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I identified the issue, the extension of above micro-service was .war and I did't notice it, after converting it to a jar, the delay was no longer their. Anyway need to check why that happened for .war extension.

Comment: There might be a library which are intended for servlet use only or wise versa. Please check on that you might find some sunshine from that :)